# how to use pipe for router link in angular2?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular-routing, angular-router, angular-pipe

i have 3 link for navigate to 3 page.all three pages almost  do one work:

```html
 <a *ngIf="item.questionnaireType==1" class="primary small ui icon button" [routerLink]="['/UpdateLikert', item.id]" title="edit">
   <i class="edit   icon"></i>
 </a>
 <a *ngIf="item.questionnaireType==2" class="primary small ui icon button" [routerLink]="['/UpdateForceChoice', item.id]" title="edit">
   <i class="edit  icon"></i>
 </a>
 <a *ngIf="item.questionnaireType==3" class="primary small ui icon button" [routerLink]="['/UpdateChoice', item.id]" title="edit">
   <i class="edit  icon"></i>
 </a>
```

but i want to have a link that dynamically route to page by it's questionnairetype.
then i create a pipe and inject in component and use it by bellow way:

```ts
  <-- pipe -->
  import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

  @Pipe({
    name: 'questionnaireTypeForRoute'
  })
  export class QuestionnaireTypeForRoutePipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value: number, args?: any): string {
      switch (value) {
        case 1: return "/UpdateLikert";
        case 2: return "/UpdateForceChoice";
        case 3: return "/UpdateChoice";
      }
    }
  }
```

using one link after create pipe:

```html
 <a  class="primary small ui icon button" [routerLink]="[{{item.questionnaireType | questionnaireTypeForRoute}}, item.id]" title="edit">
   <i class="edit icon"></i>
 </a>
```

then i  get template parse error.
is there any way to use pipe for url of routerLink ?

Comment: Remove the {{ and  }}. You're already inside an angular expression. That said, it's quite strange to have three different URLs for a single logical page: updating a questionnaire. There should be only one, and the component at that URL should be the one displaying the first, second or third component depending on what the type of the questionnaire is.

Comment: @JBNizet thanks for your help it's working but for second section please help me more ...do your mean that I use nested route?...please Introduce
 me a source

Comment: No. If you feel that this is what you should do, just use a component that uses gIf as you're doing, and inserts one of the three components. Something like `<update-likert *ngIf="questionnaire.type === 1" [questionnaire]="questionnaire"></update-likert><update-force-choice *ngIf="questionnaire.type === 1" [questionnaire]="questionnaire"></update-force-choice> ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming your posted html is within an ngFor because of the `item` property. But even if it is just a single object, you should build a routerLink property within your typescript code

```
// component.ts
getData(){
    // let data = get data somehow;

    this.data = data.map(item => {
        let routerLink;

        switch(item.questionnaireType){
             case 1:
                 routerLink = ['/UpdateLikert', item.id];
             break;
             case 2:
                 routerLink = ['/UpdateForceChoice', item.id];
             break;
             case 3:
                 routerLink = ['/UpdateChoice', item.id];
             break;
        }

        return {
            routerLink,
            id: item.id,
            questionnaireType: item.questionnaireType
        }
    });
}
```

Now you do not have to duplicate code within your html, you can simply pass in the routerLink value.

```
// component.html
<div *ngFor="let item of data">
    <a class="primary small ui icon button" [routerLink]="item.routerLink" title="edit">
        <i class="edit  icon"></i>
    </a>
</div>
```

This is essentially what you are asking for with a pipe, but moving the logic into your component code instead of a pipe.

---

**UPDATE** - Since you specifically asked about a pipe, I'll post a potential solution with a pipe

```
// pipe.ts
@Pipe({
    name: 'questionnaireTypeForRoute'
})
export class QuestionnaireTypeForRoutePipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value: number, id: number): string {
        switch (value) {
            case 1: return ["/UpdateLikert", id];
            case 2: return ["/UpdateForceChoice", id];
            case 3: return ["/UpdateChoice", id]
        }
    }
}

// component.html
<a class="primary small ui icon button" [routerLink]="item.questionnaireType | questionnaireTypeForRoute : item.id" title="edit">
    <i class="edit   icon"></i>
</a>
```

So you can see, its similar to the component.ts code. It all depends where you want to keep this kind of logic.